# Is this delegate pattern still valid in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, combine

I have been developing apps using Swift for a couple of years now. I always used Cocoa but recently decided to finally port them over to SwiftUI. I fell in love with SwiftUI pretty quickly, but whenever I develop using SwiftUI, I also ask myself the same question - is this old code still valid when using SwiftUI or this my delegate pattern no longer best practice when using it in a MVVM based app?

I am now porting my apps to SwiftUI that use a controller that hosts a timer. The timer will fire once a second and updates its model.

I wrote a small example, so let's consider this code:

```
// Controller that hosts the timer.
protocol ControllerDelegate : AnyObject {
    func controller(didRefresh value: Double)
}

class Controller {
    private var timer: Timer?

    weak var delegate: ControllerDelegate?

    @Published var value: Double = 0.0

    init() {
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.refresh), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc private func refresh() {
        // Do some stuff.
        self.delegate?.controller(didRefresh: 10.0) // Pass the result of whatever we just did to the ViewModel. Values are just an example, this could be anything.
    }
}
```

I have a Main View Model that could look like this:

```
// View Model
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    private var controller = Controller()

    @Published var value: Double = 0.0

    init() {
        self.controller.delegate = self
    }
}

extension Controller : ControllerDelegate {
    func controller(didRefresh value: Double) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

The View Model has an instance of the controller and acts as a delegate. It also has a Published property that will be bound to views, like this:

```
// View
struct ExampleView : View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text(self.viewModel.value.description)
    }
}
```

While this works quite well - is this really the way to go? Is this what Combine is for, i.e. could Combine replace the delegate pattern? What would this code look like when using Combine? Or does Combine serve another purpose?

Regards

Comment: Yes, you can use Combine to use a `Timer`/`Publisher`. Where you put that (in a `ObservableObject`, in the `View`) is all a matter of opinion.

Comment: there are no delegates or view model objects in SwiftUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no delegates or view model objects in SwiftUI the `View` struct already encapsulates view data that SwiftUI uses to init/deinit/update `UIView` objects, i.e. the actual V layer, automatically for you, so MVVM is irrelevant.

For a `View` struct that recomputes via a timer try [TimelineView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview).

> **TimelineView** A view that updates according to a schedule that you
> provide.
>
> **Overview** A timeline view acts as a container with no appearance of its
> own. Instead, it redraws the content it contains at scheduled points
> in time

Comment: Wow, I don't understand how I never heard of this View before. This sounds more like what I am looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I'd simplify it like this:

```
// View Model
@MainActor class ViewModel : ObservableObject { // <-- make it a MainActor (this is side note, not directly related to your question)
    
    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect() // <-- use this timer instead

    @Published var value: Double = 0.0
    
    func refresh() { // <-- this function will be called on timer
        // Do some stuff.
        let value = Double.random(in: 1.0...10.0) // Pass the result of whatever we just did to the ViewModel. Values are just an example, this could be anything.
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

And then UI:

```
// View
struct ExampleView : View {
    
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text(self.viewModel.value.description)
            .onReceive(viewModel.timer) { _ in // <-- executed on timer
                viewModel.refresh()
            }
    }
}
```

That's it. No need for controller or delegate

Comment: So the Timer does not call the refresh function itself, but only publishes the event to the Views which then call the refresh function. What if there are a couple of properties each assigned to a different View? Will they all have the refresh() call? it seems like with more views / properties there will be a lot of boilerplate code (do I need the onReceive each time, I assume I do)?

Comment: I think the main thing here is that yes, event is published on View, and then gives control to ViewModel, which can do what it wants. It doesn't deprive you from all the other tools that allow you to organize your code properly. For example if you have multiple views, with ViewModel each which are children of "main" view model, you could do `onReceive` only for parent (and thus have a timer once), while child viewModels implement some sort of interface parent calls to update them as well. Or you can create a custom ViewModifier which wraps `onReceive` in any way convenient and reusable for you

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you might use Combine:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

class TimerModel: ObservableObject {
    let value : AnyPublisher<Double, Never>

    init() {
        let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: RunLoop.main, in: .common).autoconnect()
        value = timer.map { _ in
            // Do some stuff
            return Double.random(in: (1.0...100.0))
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}

// View
struct ExampleView : View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: TimerModel = TimerModel()
    @State var somePercentage: Double = 0

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(String(describing: somePercentage))
            Text("%")
        }.onReceive(viewModel.value) { value in
            debugPrint(value)
            somePercentage = value
        }.frame(width: 300, height: 200)
    }
}

let exampleView = ExampleView()

PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: exampleView)
```

A way to think about this with Combine is that you really don't care about the timer.  What you really care about is a stream of values (in this case a stream of Doubles).

So in this example, the model owns a timer as the source of a model value, but the model really exposes the stream of values that make up the model.

There's nothing wrong with the delegate pattern.  It's still a perfectly valid tool.  But you could implement this in a number of different ways.